# How to formally solve a simple combinatorics question?

Tags: combinatorics

Given the universe $\mathcal{U} = \{1, 2, \ldots, n\}$, what is the number of sequences of length $k$ $(k\le n)$ s.t. all elements in a sequence are distinct and chosen from the universe $\mathcal{U}$?

Intuitively very easy, the solution must be $n \cdot (n-1)\cdot \ldots \cdot (n-k+1)$ since you have $n$ choices for the first position of the sequence, $n-1$ choices for the second position of the sequence and so on. How would I solve this question rigorously?
It is not really possible (at least that's what I think) to model this problem using sets since the choice of the $j^{\text{th}}$ position of a sequence depends on the choices for the preceding positions. The picture I have in my head is a tree, so maybe one could use this to make the argument more rigorous.

Comment: Per answer of Thomas Andrews, my *totally informal* approach is that there are $\binom{n}{k}$ ways of selecting the $(k)$ distinct elements out of $n$.  Once these $(k)$ elements are chosen, they can then be ordered in $(k!)$ ways.  So, my computation would be $\binom{n}{k} \times (k!).$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, you want to talk about bijection.

Let $S_k(\mathcal V)$ be the set of such sequences from a universe $\mathcal V.$

Show there is a bijection $S_k(\mathcal V_1)$ and $S_k(\mathcal V_2)$ if there is a bijection from $\mathcal V_1$ to $\mathcal V_2.$ So the size of $S_{k}(\mathcal V)$ only depends on the cardinality of $\mathcal V.$

Let $\mathcal U_n=\{1,2,\dots,n\}.$ For $0<k<n$ show that there is a bijection:
$$S_k(\mathcal U_n)\to U_n\times S_{k-1}(\mathcal U_{n-1}) 
$$

This would show by induction that, for $n\geq k\geq 1,$ $F_{n,k}= |S_k(\mathcal U_n)|$ satisfies the recursion:
$$F_{n,k}=\begin{cases}n&k=1\\nF_{n-1,k-1}&k>1\end{cases}$$

(Ideally start with $k=0,$ but a lot of beginners have trouble with counting sequences of length $0.$ Not knowing your level, I thought I’d save the headache.)

Comment: thanks a lot, this notation really captures the tree I had in my head!

Comment: @Rhi This is mostly boilerplate - how we fill out most counting arguments if we have to be rigorous. After a while, you’ll get a hang of why and when you can wave your hands. The second bijection, in particular, is tough to write clean, and it is the kind of rigor that adds no real value for understanding purposes, only for rigor’s sake. Combinatorics books would need to be much longer if they took this approach.